# Drupal : stop scrolling when opening a modal

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-9

I've multiple blocks in the same page which represent a login and subscribe buttons :

```
          $form['btn_actions']['subscribe_for_free_btn'] = [
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#title' => $btnJoin,
            '#url' => $subscribeLink,
            '#attributes' => [
              'class' => [
                'btn-subscribe',
                'use-ajax'
              ],
            ],
          ];

          if (!$isAuthenticated) {
            $form['btn_actions']['login_btn'] = [
              '#type' => 'link',
              '#title' => $btnLogin,
              '#url' => $loginLink,
              '#attributes' => [
                'class' => [
                  'btn-login',
                  'use-ajax'
                ],
                'data-dialog-type' => "modal"
              ],
            ];
          }
```

there's an ajax Call to open a modal when button is clicked,
Once clicked, the page will scroll to the first block in the top page.

I've tried to add an unique data-drupal-selector to each block and each button, also i've tried to add a JS function to strop scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS :
add any different class in body tag if modal is open.
Example: you add "model-open" class

then add CSS :
`.model-open{ overflow: hidden; }`